# Hiding error messages: sql query

Tags: database

I have a site running on Drupal. There is a production site, publicly seen online and a development version on a private machine.

When migrating from a devel to a production server I'd like to disable the display of error messages. This could be done in Home » Administration » Configuration » Development (D7). However I'd like to automate that; put a proper SQL query in my migration script (that packs, transfers and 'installs' the page on a production server)

Can anyone help me with that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That setting is stored in the `variable` table as a serialised PHP string (in the "error_level" var) - I wouldn't advise updating that table manually with SQL (although obviously you can if you need to).

Far better would be to install [Drush](https://drupal.org/project/drush), and use `vset` as part of your deployment process instead:

```
drush vset error_level '2'
```

The available options are:

- 0 => None
- 1 => Errors and warnings
- 2 => All messages

Comment: Also possible to put in `settings.php` file as `$conf['error_level'] = 2;`

Comment: @Beebee Good point