# Re-writing SQL statement in Drupal dynamic queries

Tags: database

I have the following SQL query, which I need to re-write using Drupal's dynamic query language. I'm new to Drupal development, could you please give me an example for the following SQL?

```
SELECT 
    node.title, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(field_data_field_location.field_location_value) 
FROM 
    node 
    INNER JOIN field_data_field_location 
        ON node.nid = field_data_field_location.entity_id 
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT 
            entity_id 
         FROM 
            field_data_field_location 
         WHERE 
            field_location_value IN ('Berlin', 'Stuttgart')) AS IDS
        ON node.nid = IDS.entity_id
GROUP BY 
    node.nid
```

---

What I currently have is the following:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->addField('n', 'title', 'title');
$query->groupBy('n.nid');

$subquery = db_select('field_data_field_location', 'loc');
$subquery->distinct();
$subquery->fields('loc.entity_id', array('eid'));
$subquery->condition('loc.field_location_value', $locations, 'IN');

$query->join('field_data_field_location', 'l', 'n.nid = l.entity_id');
$query->addExpression('GROUP_CONCAT(l.field_location_value)', 'locations');
$query->addJoin('INNER', $subquery, 'IDS', 'n.nid = IDS.entity_id');

$result = $query->execute();

return $result->fetchAll();
```

If I execute the code, I just get nothing back from Drupal. I think the problem is the subquery. Do you have any idea how I can solve that?

Comment: Here - [have an example](http://www.felixeve.co.uk/example-of-a-complex-dynamic-query-with-subqueries-in-drupal-7/) to work off. You should be able to work out what you need to do using that...

Comment: Where do you `$query->execute()` and all that? How do you fetch your data? That's an important part of code, too!

Comment: @Mołot I edited the question.

Comment: Just before `$result = $query->execute();` add something like `kpr( (string) $query);` - this will output your query, as a string, using Devel module. And you'll be able to confirm it is really what you wanted it to be. Or not.

Comment: @Molot I usually use [dpq](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpq/7)($query) - how does kpr() differ?

Comment: @FelixEve difference does not matter when we talk about your issue, really. Use what you are used to. What matters is the actual query you get from your Drupal code.

Comment: I tried it, it displays nothing. The output is empty. If I comment out `$query->addJoin('INNER', $subquery, 'IDS', 'n.nid = IDS.entity_id');` I get results. So the problem is the subquery.

Comment: So add dpq($subquery); to get the SQL of the subquery and run that to see what the problem is.

Comment: i solved it. It was a typo -.-
It should be `'n.nid = IDS.eid'` not `'n.nid = IDS.entity_id'`

Comment: @Djihad Did the raw query at the top actually work?  Trying to understand how that would have worked, but you had to do a different JOIN clause in Drupal?

Answer (score 0):

Have you turned down the [error_level](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/79425/hiding-error-messages-sql-query)? because if you get nothing back from Drupal then this typically means the query executed successfully but that no results were found. Perhaps check the `Reports->Recent log messages` for any SQL errors logged instead. This information should help you troubleshoot future Drupal SQL endeavours.

Anyway, looking over the code, I don't think this is correct:

```
$subquery->fields('loc.entity_id', array('eid'));
```

and should probably be:

```
$subquery->fields('loc', array('entity_id'));
```

or if you want to give the field an alias, use [addField](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery::addField/7):

```
$subquery->addfield('loc', 'entity_id', 'eid');
```

I've just run a similar query on a fresh database (so no custom fields) and set that fields() call correctly, and this seems to get results back:

```
$bundles = array("page", "blog");

$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->addField('n', 'title', 'title');
$query->groupBy('n.nid');

$subquery = db_select('field_data_body', 'data');
$subquery->distinct();
$subquery = $subquery->fields('data', array('entity_id'));
$subquery = $subquery->condition('data.bundle', $bundles, 'IN');

$query->join('field_revision_body', 'rev', 'n.nid = rev.entity_id');
$query->addExpression('GROUP_CONCAT(rev.bundle)', 'mybundles');
$query->addJoin('INNER', $subquery, 'IDS', 'n.nid = IDS.entity_id');

$result = $query->execute();

dpq($query); // Let's look at the query
dpm($result->fetchAll()); // Let's see all the results
```

Note, you'll need the [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module installed to use the [dpm()](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7) and [dpq()](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpq/7) functions. Hope that can help!